# Identify any NA in a data frame by ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

If I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("12","12","12","13","13","14","14"), 
Q1 = c(NA,"b",NA,"b",NA,"a","a"), 
Q2 = c(NA,"a",NA,"b",NA,"a","b"), 
Q3 = c(NA,"a",NA,"a",NA,"b","b"))
```

How can I identify the ID that has ANY NA? I just need once the ID.

What I need as a result is
`12 13`

My data frame is very large and there are some ID's with many missing values and others with not a single one. I know for sure that if one row (Q1, Q2, or Q3) has a missing value, the three of them will have an NA. All rows have ID, there are no NA in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `base R` approach using `rowSums()` in order to count the number of `NA`. After that, `which()` is used to identify the rows:

```
#Code
df[which(rowSums(is.na(df[,-1]))>0),]
```

Output:

```
  ID   Q1   Q2   Q3
1 12 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 12 <NA> <NA> <NA>
5 13 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Or if you only want the ids, you can use this:

```
#Code2
unique(df[which(rowSums(is.na(df[,-1]))>0),1])
```

Output:

```
[1] "12" "13"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the negation of `complete.case` which is exactly suited to your needs:

> A logical vector specifying which observations/rows have no missing values across the entire sequence.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("12","12","12","13","13","14","14"), 
                 Q1 = c(NA,"b",NA,"b",NA,"a","a"), 
                 Q2 = c(NA,"a",NA,"b",NA,"a","b"), 
                 Q3 = c(NA,"a",NA,"a",NA,"b","b"))


df[!complete.cases(df),1]
#> [1] "12" "12" "13"


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(df[which(rowSums(is.na(df[,-1]))>0),1],df[!complete.cases(df),1])
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                        expr  min   lq   mean median   uq   max
#>  df[which(rowSums(is.na(df[, -1])) > 0), 1] 30.0 31.2 36.600   31.7 32.5 249.4
#>                  df[!complete.cases(df), 1]  7.2  7.8  9.345    8.1  8.5  39.9
#>  neval cld
#>    100   b
#>    100  a
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It is also four times faster